# how to take screenshot of layout which is attached to windowManager

Tags: android, android-layout

in my app I am using `WindowManager` which contains 2 layouts(inner and outer).I am using `windowManager` which means it will remain on top of the screen.So my actual scenario is that I want to take the screenshot of outer layout and set that screenshot as my inner layout background.here is my code:

here the code for taking screenshot of outer layout:

```
 private static Bitmap getScreenshot(View v) {   //v=outer layout
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    v.draw(c);
    return b;
}
```

now I am setting that `Bitmap getScreenshot()` as inner layout background.So, when I tried it takes screenshot of outer layout perfectly but it does not include the items which are available  behind the layout in screenshot.It just takes screenshot of layout and if any views that are available inside the outer layout.

I have tried setting outer layout to transparent but it didn't worked.Please can anyone solve this problem.

Comment: You are not showing how and where you call that function.

Comment: `items which are available behind the layout`. Behind which layout? And you never said that you had layouts behind each other. Or what do you mean with inner and outher?

Comment: `It just takes screenshot of layout and if any views that are available inside the outer layout.` It is unclear to me what is on the screenshot. Can you explain in another way?

Comment: @greenapps let me explain you My app contain a windowManager which  contain a linearLayout.I want to take the screenshot of linearLayout but when I take the screenshot of linear layout it takes perfectly but it takes screenshot of only layout and any views(button,textview) if available inside the layout.I want it to take screenshot of layout beneath also(e.g. if my layout is present on above of my mobile home screen it should also include the hidden things(wallpaper of home screen)which are available behind the layout in the screenshot)

Comment: Still unclear. Do you want to catch things behind your layout that even the user cannot see?

Comment: @greenapps in other words I want to catch screen things which are hidden behind the windowmanager

Comment: My question was about what the user can see. Please answer to the point.

Comment: @greenapps user want to see the hidden things behind the windowManager.The hidden things may include anything like mobile home screen.

Comment: Sorry, can not help you with that. An app can only get screens of own views as far as i know. And i do not understand the subject of your post anymore.

Comment: @greenapps ok can you tell me how to blur a windowmanager so that everything behind the windowmanager will look blurred

Comment: Sorry, never done that.

Comment: @greenapps you know that BLUR_BEHIND is depricated is there any solution for that

Comment: I do not know that either.

Comment: @greenapps ok thanks anyway for your time